# smartest way to do unique ID's in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, identity

I use this code to generate a unique key for my Entities

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

I used to use other methods, but it's really important in my application to be able to insert database entries from other programs too.

The IDENTITY way is the only way I could figure out how to make it so I didn't have to worry about the incrementer logic or what not.

Are there any other strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create sequention on your DB and then you can use follow construction:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "local_genName", 
    sequenceName = "db_GenName")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, 
generator="local_genName")
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
```